# Automatic login to AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Thus far I get access to my AWS resources using Access Key Id and Secret Access Key. But every time I end my session I have to manually enter these keys when typing  `aws configure`
Is there an automated way, perhaps with SSH private key on the local host ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You should only have to run `aws configure` once, not every time you SSH into a server. Can you provide more details about exactly what you are doing? Also, if you are doing this on an EC2 server you should be using IAM roles assigned to the EC2 server instead.

Comment: @MarkB my question is much simpler than this. When I write an aws CLI based script and execute it on local machine, I sometimes have to edit the script after having closed the cmd session. In order for the script to run I'd have to use the credentials keys on cmd again to execute the script. Is there a way for the aws to authenticate my local host automatically without having to use the keys in the script or on cmd "aws configure"

Comment: When you run `aws configure` it stores the values you enter into `.aws/credentials`. You don't have to run it again.

Comment: @MarkB I see now....tnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aws provides this feature to handle access and secret keys in the format of profiles..

Let say if you have multiple accounts.. or multiple regions..

You can setup those as profiles with the help of `aws configure --profile <profilename>`

And when performing operations in one particular account in one particular region..

```
export DEFAULT_AWS_PROFILE=<profilename>
```

By doing this it is easy to work with multiple envs.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking when you use "aws configure", and enter your credentials, those credentials are saved in the .aws/credentials file in a path on your machine (exactly where will depend on the OS). You shouldn't have to run 'aws configure' again unless your credentials change.

Once that is done - one time - every further execution of an AWS CLI command should just use those stored credentials - you should not have to ever enter them more than once.